# How to go back to the previous screen when the dialog is dismissed?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem. I would like to pop the screen (of main context) when alert dialog is closed.
So here how it goes:

1. User does some staff.
2. Alert dialog is open
3. It is open for 3 seconds.
4. Alert dialog is closed
5. We move user to the main screen (**EmailPage** for me)

Whole method:

```
Future<void> _sendMessageToSupport() async {
    final body = {
      'email': emailController.text, //
      'topic': topicController.text, //
      'message': contentController.text,
    };
    final jsonString = json.encode(body);
    final uri =
        Uri.http(AppConstants.BASE_URL, AppConstants.SUPPORT_CONTACT_ENDPOINT);
    final headers = {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json'};
    _setRefreshProgressIndicator(true);
    await http.post(uri, headers: headers, body: jsonString);
    _setRefreshProgressIndicator(false);
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        Future.delayed(
          Duration(seconds: 3),
          () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            /*Navigator.push(context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EmailPage()));*/ //navigates to EmailPage rather than pop to it
          },
        );
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            'blabla',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Color(0xff000000),
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

We move to this screen (let's say A screen) from the **EmailPage**. User does staff and we should automatically back to the **EmailPage**. I have made it like this:

```
Future.delayed(
          Duration(seconds: 3),
          () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            /*Navigator.push(context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EmailPage()));*/ //navigates to EmailPage rather than pop
          },
        );
```

but the problem is we move user to **EmailPage** by pushing new screen and then when he clicks on the back arrow on the appbar he is moved to screen A again.

Could you tell me how can I do it? I mean, I know that I need to pop from context of build method, but how? When I did something like this (pop on the end of the method):

```
builder: (context) {
        Future.delayed(
          Duration(seconds: 3),
          () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
            /*Navigator.push(context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EmailPage()));*/ //navigates to EmailPage rather than pop
          },
        );
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            'Wysłano zapytanie do supportu. Postaramy się odpowiedzieć jak najszybciej!',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18,
              color: Color(0xff000000),
            ),
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
  }
```

then popup was not even shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let me know if this is not what you're looking for.

```dart
class EmailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('EmailPage')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PageA())),
          child: Text('Go to Page A'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageA extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('PageA')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Timer(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
              Navigator.pop(context); // Dismisses dialog
              Navigator.pop(context); // Navigates back to previous screen
            });

            showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                title: Text('Dialog'),
                content: Text('Dismissing in 3s'),
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Text('Show Dialog'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Alert Dialog returns a future that runs when the Dialog is Closed so you can subscribe to that future and use your pop code inside that future. /
Here is a simple example to showcase

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                    title: Text('Are you sure?'),
                    content: Text('Do you want to remove item?'),
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('Success'),
                          child: Text('NO')),
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop('Failure'),
                          child: Text('YES'))
                    ],
                  )).then((value) =>
              print('Result: ' + value.toString()));
        },
        child: Text('Show Alert Dialog'),
      ),
```